# Get Location from LocationService and update the location on presenter using MVP and Dagger 2

Tags: android, geolocation, dagger-2, android-mvp

I am new to MVP and Dagger2 , but facing the problem how to get location from my Location Service to the Presenter when there is change in  location on the method onLocationChanged().

Here I given my try :

Location Service :

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location currentLocation;
    @Inject
    EventBus bus;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ServiceComponent component = DaggerServiceComponent.builder()
                .applicationComponent(((MvpApplication) getApplication()).getComponent())
                .build();
        component.inject(this);
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("startListening")) {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        }
        else {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("stopListening")) {
                locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                locationManager = null;
            }
        }

        return START_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        currentLocation = location;
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new LocationUpdateEvent(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
        // TODO this is where you'd do something like context.sendBroadcast()
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(final String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(final String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(final String arg0, final int arg1, final Bundle arg2) {
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public LocationUpdateEvent produceLocationUpdate() {
        if (currentLocation != null) {
            return new LocationUpdateEvent(currentLocation.getLatitude(),
                    currentLocation.getLongitude());
       /* From here i want to send it to my presenter whenever location changed*/

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }
}
```

AppComponent :

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    void inject(MvpApplication app);

    void inject(LocationService service);

    @ApplicationContext
    Context context();

    Application application();

    DataManager getDataManager();

    EventBus eventBus();
}
```

Service Component :

```
@PerService
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = ServiceModule.class)
public interface ServiceComponent {
   void inject(LocationService service);
}
```

Application Module:

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

    private final Application mApplication;

    public ApplicationModule(Application application) {
        mApplication = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @ApplicationContext
    Context provideContext() {
        return mApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    Application provideApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @DatabaseInfo
    String provideDatabaseName() {
        return AppConstants.DB_NAME;
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    DataManager provideDataManager(AppDataManager appDataManager) {
        return appDataManager;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    DbHelper provideDbHelper(AppDbHelper appDbHelper) {
        return appDbHelper;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public EventBus eventBus() {
        return new EventBus();
    }

}
```

Activity Component :

```
@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = ActivityModule.class)
public interface ActivityComponent {
    void inject(SplashActivity activity);
    void inject(MainActivity activity);

}
```

Here is My presenter , that i want location from the Service :

```
public class MainActivityPresenter <V extends MainActivityMvpView> extends BasePresenter<V> implements MainActivityMvpPresenter<V> {
    private MainActivityMvpView view;

    @Inject
    public MainActivityPresenter(DataManager dataManager, SchedulerProvider schedulerProvider, CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable) {
        super(dataManager, schedulerProvider, compositeDisposable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(V mvpView) {
        super.onAttach(mvpView);

        getCompositeDisposable().add(getDataManager()
                .seeDatabaseUserInfo()
                .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
                .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
                .concatMap(new Function<Boolean, ObservableSource<Boolean>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableSource<Boolean> apply(Boolean aBoolean) throws Exception {
                        return getDataManager().seeDatabaseUserInfo();
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Boolean aBoolean) throws Exception {
                        if (!isViewAttached()) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        if (!isViewAttached()) {
                            return;
                        }
                        getMvpView().onError(R.string.error);
                    }
                }));
        view=getMvpView();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple, I'd say you should go with `Publish Subject` [(more here)](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-rxjava-subject-publish-replay-behavior-and-async-subject-224d663d452f), have a singleton wrapper with a contract to produce location updates for a publish subject and have your presenter listen to the updates by subscribing to them and decide the presentation logic.